# Maximize an app (parcellite) from a tray with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome, keyboard, gnome-shell-extension, xdotool

I would like to maximize an app (which can be thought as a left-click on the icon) which is on the right in the topbar section, just a few icons before the power-off button.
I have tried to use xdotool but with no luck. The topbar area can't be clicked with this, only area below 27 pixels from the top (and the topbar is 0-27px vertically).

Now I am thinking of writing a shell extension.
What do you reckon for that?

Comment: I just made an always on top bash program using a `yad` tray icon. It's most of what you need with the keybinding. https://snippet.host/uhakoe You just need to change the window state's in `wmctrl`. The function that toggles, and the about dialog function, just swap them to make it work  on left click of the icon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I move/maximize/activate desktop windows using \`dbus\` in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441664/how-do-i-move-maximize-activate-desktop-windows-using-dbus-in-terminal)

Comment: No, with wmctrl you cannot manage this stuff in a tray.

Comment: Command wmctrl -l gives windows but not "programms" hidden in a tray. I got 3 windows, but in a tray I have three different things. Thus, it's not the case.

Comment: I have also checked those extensions for windows, but with no luck. They don't manage this stuff, they are managing windows not programms in a tray. Check this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to maximize a window, correct?

Minimize, maximize and fullscreen from `wmctrl -h`:

```
  -r <WIN> -b <STARG>  Change the state of the window. Using this option it's
                       possible for example to make the window maximized,
                       minimized or fullscreen. The format of the <STARG>
                       argument and list of possible states is given below.
```

This will prompt you to select a window to maximize. Then you can click the icon in the tray to toggle the effect.  Right-click to set a keybinding to toggle it, or exit.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

tmp_error() {
    yad --skip-taskbar --on-top --window-icon="gtk-error" --title="Write Error" --image="gtk-error" \
        --button="Quit":1 \
        --text="Unable to write to /tmp\nCheck permissions for $USER."
    exit 1
}
export -f tmp_error

error_control() {
# Workaround:   Clicking OSK's enter-key will cause crosshair failure.
#                           wmctrl, xdotool & xprop—all fail with 'onboard' OSK.
    yad --skip-taskbar --on-top --window-icon="dialog-question" --title="Retry?" --image="dialog-question" \
        --button="Try Again":0 \
        --button="Quit":1 \
        --text="Failed to focus on the window.\nDo you want to retry?" \

    response=$?

    if [ $response -eq 0 ]; then
                select_window
    else
        exit 1
    fi
}
export -f error_control

about_dialog() {
    yad --window-icon="help-faq" --title="About" --on-top --borders=10 --center --skip-taskbar --image="preferences-system-windows" --buttons-layout="center" --text-align=center --text="Maximize Toggle\n" --button=Close!application-exit!:0
}
export -f about_dialog

set_keybinding() {
    if [ ! -f ~/.maximize_tray_xkbrc ]; then
        current_binding='[none]'
    else
        current_binding=$(sed '2q;d' ~/.maximize_tray_xkbrc)
    fi

    remove_button='rm ~/.maximize_tray_xkbrc; echo "\"bash -c 'toggle_gnome'\"" > ~/.maximize_tray_xkbrc && xdotool windowkill window="cat /tmp/xwin_id_xkb" && bash -c set_keybinding'
    show_current=$(echo "$current_binding")

    yad --window-icon="input-keyboard" --borders="15" --on-top --skip-taskbar --title="Key Binding" \
        --text-align="center" --buttons-layout="center" --text="Current Binding\n$show_current\n" \
        --separator=" " --item-separator=" " --print-xid="/tmp/xwin_id_xkb" --form  \
        --field="Hold 1:":CB "Ctrl Alt Shift" \
        --field="Hold 2:":CB "Shift Ctrl Alt" \
        --field="Action:":entry "T" \
        --field=Remove-Binding:BTN "bash -c '$remove_button'" \
        --button=Confirm:0 \
        --button=Cancel:1 > /tmp/entries

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        exit 1
    fi

    entries=$(cut -d'|' -f1 < /tmp/entries)

    f1=$(echo "$entries" | awk '{print $1}')
    f2=$(echo "$entries" | awk '{print $2}')
    f3=$(echo "$entries" | awk '{print $3}')

    key_combo=$(echo "$f1+$f2+$f3" | tr ' ' '+')

    if [ ! -f ~/.maximize_tray_xkbrc ]; then
        echo "\"bash -c 'toggle_gnome'\"" > ~/.maximize_tray_xkbrc
    fi

    echo "$key_combo" > ~/.maximize_tray_xkbrc

    # Restart xbindkeys
    killall xbindkeys
    xbindkeys --file ~/.maximize_tray_xkbrc
}
export -f set_keybinding

#!/bin/bash

toggle_effect() {
    toggle_xwin_id=$(</tmp/xwin_id)
    if xprop -id "$toggle_xwin_id" | grep -q "_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) .* _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT"; then
        wmctrl -i -r "$toggle_xwin_id" -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
    else
        wmctrl -i -r "$toggle_xwin_id" -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
    fi
}
export -f toggle_effect

select_window() {
    xdotool selectwindow > /tmp/xwin_id

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        error_control
    fi

    if [ ! -f /tmp/xwin_id ]; then
        tmp_error
    fi

    toggle_effect
}
export -f select_window

select_window

# Tray Icon & Menu
yad --notification --skip-taskbar --image="starred" \
    --command="bash -c toggle_effect" \
    --menu=" About !bash -c 'about_dialog' \
    | Keybind !bash -c 'set_keybinding' \
    | Exit !bash -c 'wmctrl -i -r $(sed '1q;d' /tmp/xwin_id) -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz && killall yad'" \
--text="Toggle Window State"

exit 0
```

Save as: `toggle_maximize.sh`
Change mode executable: `chmod +x toggle_maximize.sh`
Usage: `./toggle_maximize.sh`

Comment: Nope, I want to manage a program which is minimized to tray, with this command you cannot take this out of a tray.

Comment: After running this command I get 'xbindkeys: no process found'

Comment: `sudo apt-get install xbindkeys` will fix it.

Comment: The program xbindkeys is installed.

Comment: Ah, it's just a message from when it restarts the service, it wasn't currently running.  It's nothing bad.

Comment: I am not sure how to use it. I run your script, then there is a little star icon in a tray, I right-click on it, I get Keybind and binding is Ctrl Sht T, which I can confirm, then I get the message t 'xbindkeys: no process found'. If I use the binding it works just as ubuntu binding, it makes another tab in terminal or in chrome....I cannot change the binding keys...

Comment: When you first run the program, the cursor will become crosshairs.  Make sure your window is visible.  Then click on that window, then the star will pop up.  Clicking it will toggle.  Now that window will add/remove the vertical and horizontal maximize setting.

Comment: The problem is the window from this program is not a normal window, if you choose from the list an element, the window is automatically minimized to tray. You can install parcellite and try yourself.

Comment: I tried running this script after some sleep time. I get `Attempt to grab the mouse failed. Something already has the mouse grabbed. This can happen if you are dragging something or if there is a popup currently shown
xdo_select_window_with_click reported an error`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152059/discussion-between-jaycravens-and-szymon-roziewski).